# Web & Mobile analytics data in journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, journeybuilder, analytics, web

i want to access the data collected in Web & Mobile analytics in journeys, is there any way to access that data inside marketing cloud except the visual we see on the Web & Mobile analytics tab

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not available via API or in any of the System Data Views.

Your best bet may be to use Google Analytics and set up a middle-ware process to export that data and import it into SFMC with a triggered automation.

That's typically how I've seen it done.

Comment: ok, thanks. I too checked and didnt found any way to get that data

Comment: @adam-spriggs has this changed, as far as you know?  I'm trying to figure out whether MarketingCloud can replace Pardot as far as "web visitor stalking" for an org consolidation _(Pardot DOES expose this data through their API)_.